# Access array element use JSqlParser

Tags: jsqlparser

I insert this `sql` into JSqlParser:

```
select count(distinct case when split(vir_name,"\\/")[OFFSET(0)] in ("G-Ware","RiskWare","Tool","PornWare","Trojan") then apk_name else null end) as black_apk_n from table1
```

and get error:

> > Caused by: net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.ParseException: Encountered unexpected token: "(" "("
> >         at line 1, column 13.

It may has something to do with array access issue, how to manage the same thing in JSqlParser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately JSqlParser does not yet support these Array constructs. In fact it supports for historical reasons SQLServers and MSAccess bracket quotation like [COLUMN] instead of "COLUMN".

Here is a discussion about this: https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/issues/677.